# Adding custom error in published geoprocessing service using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

Is it possible to replace the default arcpy error message with a custom message using `arcpy.AddError(msg)` or else for a GP Service published into ArcGIS Server?

if I use:

```
arcpy.AddError("This is my custom error message")
```

My custom message only appears printed in the details. like this: (sorry its in french):

```
{
   error : {
       code: 400,
       message: "Unable to complete operation.",
       details: [
                  "Erreur d’exécution de l’outil. AppLogin Job ID:    
                      jfe0aa728897644eb9344fa9fc7a48864 : This is my custom error message
                      Échec de l’exécution de (AppLogin).
                      Échec de l’exécution de (AppLogin)."
        ]
}
```

What I want instead its just:

```
{
    error : {
        code : 400,
        message : "This is my custom error message"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting a 400 error? Thats a web server error, not an error thrown by the GP Service itself. An error produced through arcpy isn't connected to a web server error code.

Comment: GP Service published into arcgis server, the arcpy.AddError() function returns a 400 error with the message "Unable to complete operation" per default

Comment: I think the closest you can come is with `arcpy.AddIDMessage`. Some of the messages take an argument. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addidmessage.htm